# Add dictionary to MongoDB from Flask

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I have a function in Python Flask to add my data in MongoDB. Date data being collected from form is in text format but I want to save it in date format in MongoDB. So I am converting the format before inserting it to Mongo.

```
@app.route('/addtaskdb/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def addtaskdb():
    try:
        print("***********entered in addtaskdb function ")
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.form.to_dict()
            print(type(data))
            month,day, year = map(int, data['deliverydate'].split("/"))
            print(month)
            dbdate = datetime.date(year, month, day)                        
            data['deliverydate1'] = dbdate                        
            db.tasks.insert(data)
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    except Exception as e:
        flash(e)
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

I am getting following error.

```
   builtins.TypeError
TypeError: Object of type 'InvalidDocument' is not JSON serializable

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
response = self.process_response(response)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1858, in process_response
self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 924, in save_session
return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 123, in dumps
rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "C:\New folder\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "C:\New folder\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\New folder\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\New folder\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 80, in default
return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "C:\New folder\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'InvalidDocument' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I  add date in MongoDB with my current setup?

Comment: Please post your traceback in text form.

Comment: Added in text, Please let me know if anything else needed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I know it's lengthy way but helped me. Post if any pythonic way to do it.

```js
def addtaskdb():
        try:
                print("***********entered in addtaskdb function ")
                if request.method == 'POST':
                        data = request.form.to_dict()
                        pprint.pprint(data)
                        dt = data['deliverydate']
                        dx = mongodate(dt)
                        datadb = merge_two_dicts(data,dx)
                        pprint.pprint(datadb)
                        db.tasks.insert(datadb)
                        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        except Exception as e:
                flash(e)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))




def mongodate(dt):
        month,day, year = map(str, dt.split("/"))
        utcdate = str(year)+"-"+str(month)+"-"+str(day)+" 00:00:00.000000"
        date = parser.parse(utcdate)
        dx = {'date1':date}
        return dx
        

def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
        """Given two dicts, merge them into a new dict as a shallow copy."""
        z = x.copy()
        z.update(y)
        return z
```

Mongo stores the data in UTC format and it is same format as datetime.datetime output. so i convert all the string dates i was getting into utc format and boom. it works.